# not found: object akka?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am new to Scala.
 I have downloaded the Scala Eclipse IDE, and started to write a new program using akka and actors, and I am trying to import akka as follows,

```
import akka.actor._
```

but  am getting the errors as follows,
      Multiple markers at this line
    - not found: object akka
    - object actor is not a member of 
     package akka

I want to know why I am getting this error, do I need to add any other packages ?

Comment: please post your, build.sbt file or build.scala file

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a dependency to the akka-actor jar. "Getting started" section of the Akka documentation http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/intro/getting-started.html has more information on which jars to add.

Comment: how and where do i add this dependency ? how to check what dependencies are already available ?                                      i have downloaded the sbt, but i cannot find the build.sbt file

Comment: If you are using a build tool like sbt or maven, you can add the dependency there. If you are using only ScalaIDE, you can add a dependency by

Right click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries tab -> Add External Jars button.
This is exactly the same as what you with Eclipse for java.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue for some imports like akka.actor.Actor, but when i add more imports like .kernel, i still get the not found error, because i think i just added the external jars related to that akka actor package. How to integrate the whole sbt package with my scala IDE eclipse ?